# How to parse serialized json in Postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonfield

I have a data like below and I would like to get a value of sub_key1:

```
'{"key_1":"val_1", "key_2":"{\"sub_key1\":\"sub_val1\", \"sub_key2\":\"sub_val2\"}"}'
```

If I run below query, it works fine and gets me the value of key_2.

```
SELECT ('{"key_1":"val_1", "key_2":"{\"sub_key1\":\"sub_val1\", \"sub_key2\":\"sub_val2\"}"}')::json->'key_2';
```

But if I run below query, I do not get anything in return.

```
SELECT (('{"key_1":"val_1", "key_2":"{\"sub_key1\":\"sub_val1\", \"sub_key2\":\"sub_val2\"}"}')::json->'key_2')::json->'sub_key1';
```

How to get a value of sub_key1?

Comment: Try this  Select ( SELECT ('{"key_1":"val_1", "key_2":"{\"sub_key1\":\"sub_val1\", \"sub_key2\":\"sub_val2\"}"}')::json->'key_2')::json->'sub_key1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you get out by using `->` is a JSON string literal. Casting that to `json` will do nothing, and accessing a property on a string doesn't work.

You'll need to use `->>` instead to get the string as a postgres `text` which you then can convert to a `json` object:

```
SELECT (('{"key_1":"val_1", "key_2":"{\"sub_key1\":\"sub_val1\", \"sub_key2\":\"sub_val2\"}"}')::json->>'key_2')::json->'sub_key1';
```

But either way, fix the system that generates this JSON not to put serialised JSON strings into JSON.